# Homestead gives error: No input file specified. on Windows 10

Tags: laravel, homestead

I'm running Homestead under Windows 10 using VirtualBox. For some reason, no matter what I try, I get this error:

I only found a single other question similar to my issues, and the resolution there resulted in an error when running vagrant up.

No input file specified.

My *homestead.yaml* file looked like this:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

folders:
    - map: D:/code
      to: /home/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/code/test/public

sites:
    - map: info.test
      to: /home/code/info/public

sites:
    - map: food.test
      to: /home/code/food/public

databases:
    - homestead
    - food
    - info

features:
    - mysql: true
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: f
```

My [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) is:

```
192.168.10.10 homestead.test
192.168.10.10 info.test
192.168.10.10 food.test
```

The folder mappings appear to be working. If I browse *D:/code* from the host I can see the Laravel
install under *D:/code/test*. I if put a file there on the host, it's visible from [`vagrant ssh`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/ssh).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your `Homestead.yaml` file to this:

```
sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/code/test/public
    - map: info.test
      to: /home/code/info/public
    - map: food.test
      to: /home/code/food/public
```

Maybe specifying "sites" multiple times is what's breaking it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried logging in to your box with `vagrant ssh` and then doing `flip` to toggle between nginx and Apache?

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#web-servers

Comment: I had not previously tried that. I do get an error with that:                                                 
Failed to start apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not found.
apache started. I'll review the documentation you linked to. Thank you.

Comment: The link *seems* to be half-broken - there is isn't a section on it with the name "Web servers" (or similar). Can you fix it?